# unexpected output while using strlen function

Tags: pointers, sizeof, calloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char *p;
    p=calloc(10,sizeof(char));
    printf("the address of pointer is %p and size of the string is %d",p,strlen(p));
    return 0;
}
```

I allocated 10 bytes of memory in heap using calloc and i expect the output of size will be 10 but the output is

```
the address of pointer is 0x123e010 and size of the string  is 0
```

why the size is 0 and not 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strlen` simply counts the number of bytes whose value are not `0x00` (also known as `NULL`, which the C standard uses for string terminator).

Since `calloc` initializes memory to `0x00` after allocating it, `strlen` returns 0 because the first byte is already `NULL`.